# moving and rotating vertices with LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

Is it possible to move or rotate single vertices or collections of vertices(for example display lists)instead of changing the coordinates of every single vertex with the LWJGL?

Maybe something like `GL11.glTranslatef(...)` but only for moving parts of the scene.
In addition J have no idea how to rotate something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenGL 2.0 with vertex shader to do this. But it's not so simple like glTranslatef.

Google: `OpenGL 2.0 Vertex Transformation`. It allows rotate, scale and move vertices.